# TSP Edge Removal

Tags: algorithms, graphs, optimization, traveling-salesman

Are there any papers/algorithms for finding edges in a graph that can be removed with affecting the graph's optimal TSP tour length?

For instance, in a Euclidean TSP instance, many edges could be ruled out for being too long (i.e., jumping between very far apart nodes) given a decent upper bound on the optimal tour length. Is there some efficient heuristic algorithm for eliminating edges like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See "Edge elimination in TSP instances", Hougardy and Schroeder, 2014, http://arxiv.org/abs/1402.7301